# Android: deleting entries from MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members table

Tags: android, mediastore

I am writing an Android music player capable of editing MP3 song genres.

The procedure I'm following is:

1. Edit the genre tag in the MP3 file itself
2. Update the SqlLite MediaStore.Audio.Genres tables to reflect the changes (I do not want to trigger a lengthy 'rescan' operation for Android to pickup the changes itself)

My research suggests I need to modify MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members table (ie this is the table I use to fetch the genre info).

My issue is a seemingly simple delete operation is not working as expected.

Note: I do know NOT to use hardcoded URIs as shown, but this is just test code...

```
String uriStr = "content://media/external/audio/genres/2/members";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);

// Query the table for the row with ID=5448
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, BaseColumns._ID + "=5448", null, null);
Log.v("Test", "Row count: " + cursor.getCount());
cursor.close();

// Try to delete row 5448
int rowsCount = context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, BaseColumns._ID + "=5448", null);
Log.v("Test", "Rows deleted: " + rowsCount);

// Try (again) to delete row 5448
rowsCount = mService.getContentResolver().delete(uri, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[]{"5448"});
Log.v("Test", "Rows deleted: " + rowsCount);

// Query (again) the table for the row with ID=5448         
Cursor cursor1 = mService.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, BaseColumns._ID + "=5448", null, null);
Log.v("Test", "Row count: " + cursor1.getCount());
cursor1.close();
```

The log of the above code is...

```
Row count: 1
Rows deleted: 0
Rows deleted: 0
Row count: 1
```

Why does the above **query** return a valid entry, but the **deletes** fail???

Comment: I have a problem changing the genre name from an audiofile by updating the mediastore.audio.genres.NAME table, did you found a solution for this?

Comment: Check out my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658064/how-to-update-genre-in-mediastore

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to edit the table. The android will automatically update this with what it finds on your tagged music. Why not look at the problem from an mp3 perspective? Present the user with a list of Genres, offer a replace function and then update the tracks with the new genre,

Comment: Have you tried? Because I don't think that Android is updating the Genre tablet. Genre is really a mess in android. As far I can see I have a lot of empty genre and when I update genre tag in MP3 ID3TAG it won't refresh the genre in the MediaStore (other changes in track name, album or artist will update it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need this more but if you do i can advice the solution i used:
when you are displaying genres, just check the number of tracks each genre has and if it's 0 just don't display this genre.

Answer (score 0):

You would rather use the AUDIO_ID column and not BaseColumns._ID because it is possible that row ids are updated each time you delete a row.

Here is what I do in my own app (tested and working fine on Android 4.0.4) :

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri(
                "external", genreId), MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.AUDIO_ID + " = " + song.getId(), null);
```