# How to update genre in mediastore?

Tags: java, android, uri, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I'm trying to update the genre tag of an audio file.

**CODE**

```
final Uri genreUri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

String currentGenreName = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME;

ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
values2.put(currentGenreName, genre);

String whereGenre = MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID + "=?";
String[] whereVal2 = {Long.toString(genreID)};
resolver.update(genreUri, values2, whereGenre, whereVal2);
```

- **genre**:  value from edittext (new genre name).
- **genreID**: genreID from selected audio file.

I'm not getting any errors, but the genre doesn't update in the MediaStore genre table.

Other tags like Title, artist, album and art are updated, only genre doesn't work.

I also can't find any information about updating the genre name in an audio file, I only managed to do it with the tags above.

**EDIT**

CODE I use for editing the title, artist, albumname and year tags and this works fine so I figured i had to do the same for the genre name because I have the genre id.

```
final Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;


ContentResolver resolver = c.getContentResolver();

String currentTitle     = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
String currentArtist    = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
String currentAlbumID   = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;
String currentAlbum     = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
String currentGenreID   = MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID;
String currentGenreName = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME;
String currentAlbumData = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
String currentYear      = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(currentTitle, title);
values.put(currentArtist, artist);
values.put(currentAlbum, album);
values.put(currentYear, year);

//Update song info.
String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=?";
String[] whereVal = {Long.toString(songID)};
resolver.update(musicUri, values, where, whereVal);
```

Any reason why it's not updating?

Comment: The problem is resolved??

Comment: @abhinandansharma No, i can't find anything about this.

Comment: @abhinandansharma any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: @abhinandansharma If you know a solution, can you let me know or point me in the right direction to solve this because i still have not found a way to make it work.

Comment: Hello. I have a working code for changing the genre. It is similar to yours and it works. It works on pre-Q only. Anyway, I use `MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME` instead of id on projection. I also use `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`  instead of `MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` Apply those changes to the first block of code to the top. Hope this helps.